# Random line through a polygon

Tags: algorithm, geometry

The problem:

I have trouble generating a random line that cuts through a polygon (not necessary convex).
The lines should have the same distribution as completely random lines (random position, random angle), disregarding those that miss the polygon entirely.

My thoughts so far:

Picking a random point inside the polygon (I have that algorithm already) and picking a random angle won't do, because a hammer shaped object would be cut more often through the head (it has a larger area than the handle), where a completely random line would be more likely to cut through the handle. Also the angle would defenitely not be uniformly distributed.

For the same reasons it's not possible picking two points inside or on the surface and generating a line that goes through both points or any similar methods.

Edit: I have two methods that I can use but I'm not perfectly satisfied with either of them.

1. Find a circle that contains the polygon. Pick random lines through the circle until you find one that also cuts through the polygon. This basically the definition that I wrote above only with a higher chance of hitting the polygon.
2. Project the polygon in n directions (e.g. 0°, 10°, 20° etc.). The size of the projection is proportional to the likelyhood of getting hit from this direction. Then I pick a direction (using the projection-size as weighted probabilies). Finally, I can add a 360/n° jitter the the angle. This should approximate the distribution well enough but I wonder if there is a better way of doing it.

**Edit2**: -deleted-
I had written quite a lot but after thinking some more about it and discovering some mistakes I realized that this is getting over my head.
The idea was to project a convex hull of the polygon in just a few, certain directions and finding a function that gives us all the other projections by blending between the known ones. But the details turned out to be quite convoluted and just too much for me at the moment.

Comment: I assert from your story that any line should cut the polygon in exactly two pieces, correct?

Comment: I don't care for the number of resulting pieces. Concave polygons could be split into more than two pieces. Theoretically, it could even result in only one piece if the line only just touches the polygon (but with probability 0).

Comment: Interesting. Not a complete solution, but have you considered randomly selecting points within the convex hull of the polygon?

Comment: As you, I think, correctly state that selecting a starting point(s) based on the polygon will yield a biased and non-uniformly distributed collection of lines. A good starting point therefore seems to define a canvas in which the polygon lies and generate random lines based on random coordinates and angles within the canvas. We should mathematically verify that if you omit all the lines that do not intersect the polygon, the remaining collection is still uniformly randomly distributed

Comment: Solution number 1 in your edit is what I was hinting at. You say that it is the same as initially described, but I beg to differ, because in point 1, there is no bias introduced by choosing lines based on the polygon structure. Disregarding my point about having to prove whether the collection of lines, not containing the lines that do not intersect the polygon, are still uniformly randomly distributed, what do you not like about this method?

Comment: Pankrates: I had't yet read your comment when I wrote the edit. I used a circle because a it's easy to see that a circle doesn't introduce any bias and it should be easy to find random lines that go through the circle. (I haven't thought too much about it but picking two random points inside the circle should work).

Comment: Pankrates: continued: Ah, I see now what you mean with "what do you not like with this method" :). I thought you meant why do I dislike YOUR reply. What I don't like with this method is that the algorithm may miss the shape hundreds of times before it hits.

Comment: And when I wrote "This basically the definition that I wrote above" I meant the original definition of the line distribution "The lines should have the same distribution as completely random lines (random position, random angle), disregarding those that miss the polygon entirely.".

Comment: The reason I suggested selecting points from within the convex hull (as opposed to the enclosing circle) is that any line containing a point *inside* the convex hull is guaranteed to intersect the polygon. A line through a point entirely on one edge of the convex hull will intersect the polygon as long as the line is not parallel with the edge. A line through a point on a vertex of the convex hull will intersect the polygon if it passes between the two adjacent vertices.

Comment: Beaker: If I pick random point on the convex hull it might pick two points on the same line, generating a cutting line that only touches the polygon with a way more likelyhood than is proper. After I picked the first point, the probabilities of the socond one are not easy to figure out.

Comment: Continued: It can be done mathematically (the probability p of point q2 given q1 should be something like |dq| * |dot(norm(dq), tq2))| where dq = q2 - q1 and tq2 is the tangent at q2. You can probably make a function for a straight lien that maps the points on the line to the probability-weight. However, I would have to inverse that function and that could be messy. These are just my first thoughts, but I think I will try to work it out and post again after that.

Comment: Once you have the first point inside the convex hull, you can either select a random angle or a second point *anywhere* (it doesn't have to be within the convex hull).

Comment: You'll probably want to read up on [Bertrand's Paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)). To summarize: the notion of a *random line intersecting a figure* is not well-defined, at least not without specifying some more properties that you need the distribution of lines to satisfy.

Comment: I think I defined the properties of the line distribution adequately. I want the same distribution as the solution 1 in my original post. Picking a point in or on the convex hull and then using a random angle does not result in the same distribution.

Comment: it's not clear to me that your (1) will work, btw.  it seems possible to me that it could have a radial bias in line density (there's no symmetry argument against).

Comment: Andrew Cooke: Hm, I think you are correct. I think you have to pick a random direction and project the circle on this direction and then find a random point on the projection. That should have no bias.

Comment: btw typically you can post an answer to your own question.  if you cannot see a way to do that it may be because you do not yet have enough karma or points or whatever they are called.  so use the site a bit (gain some more points) and then come back and it may appear...  and then you have to wait some more (days?) before you can mark it correct! :)

Comment: I have to wait one more hour, then I will post it as answer. Then it will also be easier to ask questions and discuss because this is probably pretty hard to understand without drawings.

Answer (score 3):

The notion of *random line intersecting with a figure* is surprisingly awkward to define rigorously: see [Bertrand's paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)) for a well-known example of the ambiguity in this kind of idea. Even a *random line in the plane* is not easy to define: you might try something like "a line passing at a random angle through a random point", but how do you choose a random point? There's no uniform distribution over points in the plane.

Here's a way to precisely define *random line intersecting with a figure F*. Let *w*(θ) be the width of the figure *F* perpendicular to the angle θ:

[image]

When *F* is a polygon, then *w*(θ) is made out of piecewise sine functions, with as many pieces as the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of the polygon has [antipodal pairs of vertices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipodal_point#Antipodal_pair_of_points_on_a_convex_polygon).

Now, choose an angle θ using *p*(θ) as the probability density function, where

> *p*(θ) = *w*(θ) / ∫ *w*(θ) dθ

and then choose the position of the line uniformly on the interval [0, *w*(θ)].

(Your method #2 tries to approximate *p*(θ) by sampling a small number of values of θ and constructing a piecewise-constant distribution. But we can get an exact result without too much extra difficulty.)

To compute the integral ∫ *w*(θ) dθ (and thus *p*(θ)), first find the [convex hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of your polygon, and then use the [rotating calipers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotating_calipers) method to find the [antipodal pairs of vertices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antipodal_point#Antipodal_pair_of_points_on_a_convex_polygon). Between adjacent antipodal pairs, the calipers move from θ<sub>0</sub> to θ<sub>1</sub>, say, and in this range *w*(θ) is given by

> *w*(θ) = *d* sin(θ − φ)

where φ is the angle of the line between the antipodal vertices *d* is its length, as shown in the two figures below:

[image]

[image]

Now over the range θ<sub>0</sub> to θ<sub>1</sub>, the indefinite integral is:

> ∫ *w*(θ) dθ = ∫ *d* sin(θ − φ) dθ = − *d* cos(θ − φ)

and so the definite integral of *w*(θ) for the range [θ<sub>0</sub>, θ<sub>1</sub>] is

> *d* (cos(θ<sub>0</sub> − φ) − cos(θ<sub>1</sub> − φ))

Sum this up over all pairs of antipodal points and you've computed the whole integral.